# Youtube video processing status stuck on "processing" after an upload with the google api php client

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I have a problem uploading a video on my youtube account using the google api php client 0.6.4

The upload seems ok but the video status is stuck on "processing"

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [uploadStatus] => uploaded
            [privacyStatus] => public
            [license] => youtube
            [embeddable] => 1
            [publicStatsViewable] => 1
        )
    [processingDetails] => Array
        (
            [processingStatus] => processing
            [fileDetailsAvailability] => inProgress
            [processingIssuesAvailability] => inProgress
            [tagSuggestionsAvailability] => inProgress
            [editorSuggestionsAvailability] => inProgress
            [thumbnailsAvailability] => inProgress
        )

)
```

Has someone an advice on this ?

Thanks !

** UPDATE **

The processingDetails has change lately, but the status is still stuck on "processing"

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [uploadStatus] => uploaded
            [privacyStatus] => public
            [license] => youtube
            [embeddable] => 1
            [publicStatsViewable] => 1
        )
    [fileDetails] => Array
        (
            [fileType] => video
            [container] => mov
        )
    [processingDetails] => Array
        (
            [processingStatus] => processing
            [fileDetailsAvailability] => available
            [processingIssuesAvailability] => available
            [tagSuggestionsAvailability] => inProgress
            [editorSuggestionsAvailability] => inProgress
            [thumbnailsAvailability] => inProgress
        )
    [suggestions] => Array
        (
            [processingHints] => Array
                (
                    [0] => nonStreamableMov
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the API upload succeeded then things sound like they're working as intended from the API perspective. What I'd recommend doing is trying to upload the same raw video file via the browser at http://www.youtube.com/upload and see if that video is successfully processed or also gets stuck.

If it also gets stuck, then the problem is your video.

If it gets processed, then there might have been some one-off problem that affected your upload via the API, and I'd suggest retrying. If the problem is consistent with API uploads (and try with different files, too) then it sounds like a bug with the client library.

Comment: I tried with the youtube video manager, and everything goes well.

Comment: Then I'd recommend trying a couple of time with the same video file using the API and see if each of those uploads also get stuck in Processing. If so, the client library is probably doing something incorrect, and you should open a bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/list

Comment: I still trying to upload a video. I open a bug for this, but they don't have answers. However the processingDetails has change lately.

Comment: I have this same issue. If anyone knows how to solve this issue, please let us know. Thank you.

Comment: You might be running into https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5700