# Upload failed: Can't process file (Video uploaded via google youtube API)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Google YouTube API demo application to upload video to youtube. I got 200 response code from google but can't see the video file. Now if I go to my youtube account to see list of video uploaded, found " Upload failed: Can't process file". Please check my attached screen shot and response body:

```
responseBody:protected
]=>{  
"kind":"youtube#video",
"etag":"\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/g2r-EnOHW5MpVltTX_2yOkmTkp0\"",
"id":"AwLj-Vd1xvg",
"snippet":{  
   "publishedAt":"2017-11-08T07:13:47.000Z",
   "channelId":"UCSdakp1jDxb7-TcaxmPux1A",
   "title":"Spencers Recipe123",
   "description":"Test by spenvcer",
   "thumbnails":{  
      "default":{  
         "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AwLj-Vd1xvg/default.jpg",
         "width":120,
         "height":90
      },
      "medium":{  
         "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AwLj-Vd1xvg/mqdefault.jpg",
         "width":320,
         "height":180
      },
      "high":{  
         "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AwLj-Vd1xvg/hqdefault.jpg",
         "width":480,
         "height":360
      }
   },
   "channelTitle":"Srijabrat Dolai",
   "tags":[  
      "tag"
   ],
   "categoryId":"22",
   "liveBroadcastContent":"none",
   "localized":{  
      "title":"Spencers Recipe123",
      "description":"Test by spenvcer"
   }
},
"status":{  
   "uploadStatus":"uploaded",
   "privacyStatus":"unlisted",
   "license":"youtube",
   "embeddable":true,
   "publicStatsViewable":true
}
}
```

Comment: Is it just for that specific video? Did you try re-uploading it? You can also check in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17933848/5995040) where you issue belongs to.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? I am having the same problem. I am uploading form Java. Everything works perfectly in the code, but on the youtube website I get the error displayed above

Comment: I am also getting the same error. If anyone one can find a valid solution for this, I will say him legend.